# Set Table height to fixed height

Tags: tables, margins, height

I found the `\resizebox` command but I don't want to scale my table. I want to be able to set it to X height and have it stay there. Is there a way to set the height of a table and leave it there no matter how many rows?

I ask since the table in the middle of my document will always vary and sometimes have one row and sometimes have 4 rows. When I set it up to one row with measurements and then add more rows it moves my items below it.

I want that when I add more rows to the table in the middle it doesn't move the content below it. So I was figuring that setting the height to begin with will solve that, I just can't find how to set that height parameter.

This is my table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{0.5in} p{3.25in} p{0.5in} @{} }
\textbf{date} & \textbf{date} & \textbf{date} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your table in a `minipage` with a fixed height:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][4in][t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{0.5in} p{3.25in} p{0.5in} @{} }
\textbf{date} & \textbf{date} & \textbf{date} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

The first optional argument tells what's the alignment of the `minipage` with respect to the context (it may well be also `c`). The second optional argument tells how much vertical size is reserved to the `minipage` (just figure out what you need). The third optional argument is the "inner alignment": it can be `t` for "top alignment", `c` for "center alignment", `b` for "bottom alignment and also `s` for "stretch all vertical spaces"; here the alignment is with respect to the top and the bottom of the reserved space. The `s` option doesn't make sense in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you Use Heiko Oberdiek’s [tabularht](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabularht)-package from his [oberdiek](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek)-bundle. The package gives you the possibility to specify the height of the tabular.

Two MWEs:

```
% Table 1
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array,tabularht}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularht}{50mm}{|l|l|}
Hello & World\\
Foo & Bar\\
Bar&foo\\\noalign{\vfill}
\end{tabularht}
\end{document}

% Table 2
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array,tabularht}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularht}{50mm}{|l|l|}
Hello & World\\
\interrowfill
Foo & Bar\\
Bar&foo\\
\end{tabularht}
\end{document}
```

Tabel 1 [image] Table 2 [image]

Both tables have the same high, but table 2 fills the excess white space between two rows, table 1 places the white space after the last row.