# How to build a table of fixed width and fixed height? (Edit: the question left now is about color overwrite)

Tags: tables, overleaf

```
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{equation*}
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}

                  & aaaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaa \\ \cline{2-4}
                $A_A \prec_B C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}   
                        &
                    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}   
                \\ \cline{2-4}
                $A_A {\tiny\cancel{\overset{\prec}{\underset{\succ}{\approx}}}_B} C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} 
                        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
                     
                \\ \cline{2-4}
                $A_A=C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
                     
                \\ \cline{2-4}
                $A_A \succ_B C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
                \\ \cline{2-4}
                
            \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
```

(**Deleted**)*The problem of width is caused by each column having different numbers of "a". And the problem of height is caused by a customized large symbol.
I tried to replace the initial four "c" with "p{4cm}", but it does not respond at all. (this is for adjusting the width. As for height, shall I use something like "\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}"?) I have searched some threads, but their table starts with format like {|c|c|} and I feel that my case does not fit in?*

**There is also another problem: some lines are covered by the gray block. I tried to move \cline before \ rather than after \, but it always says "error". There are some relevant thread: [Cellcolor overwrites partial horizontal lines (\cline)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/cellcolor-overwrites-partial-horizontal-lines-cline)
But their tables start with something like {|c|c|}, so all the border lines are present, which is inconsistent with my case.**

Thank you very much!

Edit(**delted**):

```
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][6in][t]{\textwidth}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{} c p{1in} p{1in} p{1in} @{}}

              & aaaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaa \\ \cline{2-4}
            $A_A \prec_B C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}   
                    &
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}   
            \\ \cline{2-4}
            $A_A \cancel{\overset{\prec}{\underset{\succ}{\approx}}}_B C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
                 
            \\ \cline{2-4}
            $A_A=C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
                 
            \\ \cline{2-4}
            $A_A \succ_B C_C$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
            \\ \cline{2-4}
            
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71452/set-table-height-to-fixed-height?rq=1

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354641/simpler-solution-of-table-cell-color-overlaps-cell-border?rq=1

Comment: @jsbibra Thank you very much! I tried the first one, it looks the width is OK, but the "aaaa" is not centered. As for the height, it does not respond at all. My new code is now in my question.

Comment: if just centering why not use `c` type columns

Comment: @jsbibra What I want is: the text is centered, but the width is fixed.

Comment: Why do you want a table of fixed width and height? Does this have to do with filling a table across multiple slides within the same frame and you don't want it to "move around"?

Comment: @Werner Ah, that's a good point. Initially, I feel that a table with fixed width and height is "beautiful". But maybe that is too demanding...Then I guess the real problem left is the "color covers lines". I searched several threads, but it seems that their solution is for a table that every border line is solid.

Comment: @Ypbor: You didn't answer the question. Are you concerned about the table jumping between slides because the content varies?

Comment: @Werner No, that is not my concern. But I would like to learn the solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

- The key `columns-width=auto` sets the width of all the columns to the largest one.
- I have set `\arraystretch` to 1.4, which, in your case, is enough to have all the rows of the same height.
- The command `\Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}` creates a block with no content (the last argument) but which is used to have all the rules drawn in that block (with the key `hvlines`).
- With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the rules are drawn by PGF (a sublayer of Tikz) after the construction of the array and that ensure a perfect result with the colored cells, in all the PDF viewers). However, you need *several compilations*.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[colortbl-like,columns-width=auto]
& aaaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaa \\ 
$A_A \prec_B C_C$ & \Block[hvlines]{*-*}{} \\
$A_A {\tiny\cancel{\overset{\prec}{\underset{\succ}{\approx}}}_B} C_C$ & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
$A_A=C_C$ & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
$A_A \succ_B C_C$ & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how to execute "several compilations".

Comment: As usual with LaTeX, compilations mus be done until the `aux` file does not change. Several tools, such as `latexmk` does directly the right number of compilations. Overleaf, for instance, uses `latexmk` (afaik) and the right number of compilations is always done.

Comment: Actually, I am using Overleaf. But when I copy and paste your code in, it shows several errors including "The option 'colortbl-like' is unknown for the missing number, treated as 0".

Comment: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Sorry my question may be stupid. But I went to the link you provided, but what I download is a txt file. And it does not work even if I uploaded it to Overleaf. I also created a tex file in which I pasted the code of txt in, but it also did not work. I guess I have a misunderstanding about sty file.

Comment: The file must be named `nicematrix.sty` and not `nicematrix.txt`. If you have succeeded to have the right file but with the name `nicematrix.txt`, you have to rename it in `nicematrix.sty` and then upload it in your Overleaf repertory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130381/discussion-between-ypbor-and-f-pantigny).

Comment: @Ypbor Please consider accepting and upvoting the provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `scalebox` (defined in the `adjustbox` package) and `tabularay` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} % tested with version 2021P

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[r,$] *3{X[c]}}, % or Q[r,mode=math]
                 hline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
                 vline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
                 row{2-Z} = {ht=4ex}
                }
                & aaaaaaaaaa            & aaaaaaaaa         & aaaaaaaaaaaaa \\
A_A \prec_B C_C &                       &                   &               \\
A_A  \scalebox{0.7}{$\cancel{\overset{\prec}{\underset{\succ}{\approx}}}$}_B C_C
                & \SetCell{gray!50}     &                   &               \\
A_A=C_C         & \SetCell{gray!50}     & \SetCell{gray!50} &               \\
A_A \succ_B C_C & \SetCell{gray!50}     & \SetCell{gray!50} &               \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (1):**
Now columns 2 - 4 have equal width (and height).

**Edit (2):**
If you use Overleaf, you need to load/install the package `tabularrray` and `ninecolors` (which is requiewd by `taabularray`) yourself. Since I'm not familiar with Overleaf, I can't advice you, how to do this, but their support is very friendly and and they will be happy to help you with that.

Also you not need to use `adjustbox` package if for math expression in the second row use suggestion in the @Mico answer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} % tested with version 2021P

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[r,$] *3{X[c]}}, % or Q[r,mode=math]
                 hline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
                 vline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
                 row{2-Z} = {ht=4ex}
                }
                & aaaaaaaaaa            & aaaaaaaaa         & aaaaaaaaaaaaa \\
A_A \prec_B C_C &                       &                   &               \\
A_A \mathrel{\scriptstyle\cancel{\overset{\prec}{\underset{\succ}{\approx}}}_B} C_C % adopted from @Mico suggestion
                & \SetCell{gray!50}     &                   &               \\
A_A=C_C         & \SetCell{gray!50}     & \SetCell{gray!50} &               \\
A_A \succ_B C_C & \SetCell{gray!50}     & \SetCell{gray!50} &               \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comment:

- if you like to add some (complete) rows below existing, then just write it, as I did in MWE below (I don't know what is content of this row)
- if you only like have multiline content of particular cell, than yo add this text to this cell:

  - in case that text is long enough, it will break in `X` column types into two lines automatically, for example `new text aaaaaaaaa`
  - if it is shorter, than you need to break it manually, for example `new\\ aaaaaaaaa`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} % tested with version 2021P

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[r,$] *3{X[c,b]}}, % or Q[r,mode=math]
                 hline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
                 vline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
                 row{2-Z} = {ht=4ex}
                }
                & aaaaaaaaaa            & new text 
                                          aaaaaaaaa         
                                                            & aaaaaaaaaaaaa \\
A_A \prec_B C_C &                       &                   &               \\
A_A \mathrel{\scriptstyle\cancel{\overset{\prec}{\underset{\succ}{\approx}}}_B} C_C % adopted from @Mico suggestion
                & \SetCell{gray!50}     &                   &               \\
A_A=C_C         & \SetCell{gray!50}     & \SetCell{gray!50} &               \\
A_A \succ_B C_C & \SetCell{gray!50}     & \SetCell{gray!50} &               \\
A_A \nprec_B C_C    & \SetCell{gray!50} & \SetCell{gray!50} & \SetCell{gray!50}              \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

I tested all the examples with the latest MiKTEX program. The compilation was without warnings or errors. If you use Overleaf (as I concluded from one of your comment to other answers) then you may have problems with compilation. In this case please contact their support team and ask for help.

I allowed myself to add an overleaf tag to your question that you will get their attention.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to add one more row above the current one which only contains text above the second aaaa; and one more row below the current one which only contains text below A_A \succ_B C_C. I feel that your answer is the one which is most friendly to this modification. But I cannot even compile your original code.  I downloaded the tabularray file. But there are many errors including "Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands."

Comment: @Ypbor, see addendum to answer, if I understood your comment correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I would wipe out *all* lines -- horizontal & vertical -- within the shaded area.

[image]

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{cancel,xcolor,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcommand\cc{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|*{3}{C|}}
\cline{2-4}
& aaaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaa \\ 
\cline{2-4}
$A_A \prec_B C_C$ 
   & & & \\ \cline{2-4}
$A_A \mathrel{{\scriptscriptstyle\cancel{\overset{\prec}{\underset{\succ}{\approx}}}_B}} C_C$ 
   & \cc &     & \\ \cline{2-4}
$A_A=C_C$ 
   & \cc & \cc & \\ \cline{2-4}
$A_A \succ_B C_C$ 
   & \cc & \cc & \\ \cline{2-4}        
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for use of `mathrel` !