# How to build a table with partial border lines and fixed width (and height)?

Tags: tables

This is a derived question of [How to build a table of fixed width and fixed height? (Edit: the question left now is about color overwrite)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618287/how-to-build-a-table-of-fixed-width-and-fixed-height-edit-the-question-left-n)

Now I don't need to worry about the color. The layout I want to achieve is as follows:
[image]

I try to modify the code of @F. Pantigny to achieve this:

```
\begin{frame}{Title}

\centering

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[colortbl-like,columns-width=auto]
 & & $A\left(B_C\right)$ & \\

& {\small aaaaaaaaaa} & {\small aaaaaaaaa} & {\small aaaaaaaaaaaaa} \\ 
{\small ABC} & \Block[hvlines]{*-*}{} $\times$ & $\checkmark-$ & $\checkmark$\\
{\small non-IBC but DEF} & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ \\
{\small non-DEF} & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark+$ \\
$A\left(A_A, B_{BC}\right)$ & & & 
\end{NiceTabular}


\end{frame}
```

But the above code makes the last row have border line. I think that is because of "\Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}". But if I delete it, I will lose all the border lines.
I was wondering how to circumvent this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a complete code example that can be compiled and not just a partial code. You can take user F. Pantignyas as a role model in the referenced answer that you provide. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 for more information.

Comment: I have trouble following/understanding your question. Could be more specific about what is the indented output?

Comment: just add the number of rows in the block command that is three rows and all columns(*) -- dont be scared to experiment with 4-* or 2-* etc in the `Block` command

Comment: you have answered this question in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618287/how-to-build-a-table-of-fixed-width-and-fixed-height-edit-the-question-left-n/618311#618311.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[colortbl-like,columns-width=auto]
 & & $A\left(B_C\right)$ & \\

& {\small aaaaaaaaaa} & {\small aaaaaaaaa} & {\small aaaaaaaaaaaaa} \\ 
{\small ABC} & \Block[hvlines]{3-*}{} $\times$ & $\checkmark-$ & $\checkmark$\\
{\small non-IBC but DEF} & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ \\
{\small non-DEF} & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark+$ \\
$A\left(A_A, B_{BC}\right)$ & & & 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could have simplified a bit the code with `\RowStyle{\small}` in the first line and `>{\small}` in the premable... (+1)

Comment: thanx -- just acted on the ambiguity expressed by the OP and not visual impact